# Applying 2d Array To Methods Plus Return Statements (Java)

Tags: java, array

I have an assignment that I have completed, but I feel as though the way I went about solving the problems could be optimized a bit. As well, I don't know if I'm properly utilizing return statements. I'm relatively new to coding so I don't have the knowledge, but I would love to learn if anyone wants to go through and see if they can help me, even just pointing me in the right direction without actually giving me a definitive answer would be fantastic.

Here is the problem: Write a program that displays, examines and manipulates a two dimensional array representing plane seats for a plane with 12 rows and 4 seats per row. Write methods for the following operations:

fillSeatsRandomly:Fills the array with random values in range from 0 to 1. Zero represents an empty seat and one represents a reserved seat.

displaySeats: Displays all the seats in the plane row by row. Empty seat is displayed as 0 and a reserved seat is displayed as X. Create vertical headings for the row numbers from 1 to 12 on the left hand side and horizontal column headings from A to D (for the 4 seats in the row).

isSeatAvailable: Receives an integer representing a row number and a character representing a seat from A to D. This method tests if the specified seat is available, otherwise it returns false. This method displays an error message when the seat selection is invalid.

reserveSeat: Reserves a specified seat. Receives two parameters: an integer representing a row number and a character representing a seat number from A to D. This method displays an error message when the seat is invalid.

seatsAvailInRow: counts and returns number of seats available in given row. Receives an integer representing row number.

findRowWithTwoSeats: This method look for the closest row with two adjacent available seats. If two adjacent seats are not available it returns 0.

countSeatsAvail: counts the number of all seats available in the plane and returns that number.

countTakenSeats: counts the number of all seats reserved in the plane and returns that number.

Here is my code

```java
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] plane;//this is the array that will be plugged into the methods
        plane = fillSeatsRandomly();//creates the 12x4 array that will be used
        displaySeats(plane);//shows the user what seats are available/taken
        isSeatAvailable(plane);//allows the user to see if a seat is available
        reserveSeat(plane);//allows the user to reserve a seat
        displaySeats(plane);//shows the user their seat has been reserved
        seatsAvailInRow(plane);//shows how many seats are avail in given row
        findRowWithTwoSeats(plane);//finds closest row with adjacent seats
        countSeatsAvail(plane);//counts how many seats are available
        countTakenSeats(plane);//counts how many seats are taken
    }

    public static void displaySeats(int seats[][]) {//displays the seats
        System.out.print("\tA  \tB  \tC  \tD \n");
        for (int row = 0; row < seats.length; row++) {
            System.out.print(row + 1 + "");
            for (int seatNum = 0; seatNum < seats[row].length; seatNum++) {
                if (seats[row][seatNum] == 1) {
                    System.out.print("\tX  ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("\t0  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int[][] fillSeatsRandomly() {//fills seats randomly, returns
        //an array of seats either filled or empty 
        int[][] rndm = new int[12][4];
        for (int[] rndm1 : rndm) {
            for (int col = 0; col < rndm1.length; col++) {
                rndm1[col] = (int) Math.round(Math.random());
            }
        }
        return rndm;//return the array
    }//end of fillSeatsRandomly

    public static boolean isSeatAvailable(int[][] plane) {//asks user for input
        //checks if seat is available, returns true if it is and false if not
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rowNum;//row number of the seat chosen
        int colNum = 4;//column of the seat chosen
        char seatSelect;//character of the seat chosen
        String str;//used to get char value for switch
        System.out.println("Choose which row you would like to check (1-12)");
        rowNum = input.nextInt() - 1;
        System.out.println("Choose which seat you would like: A,B,C, or D (Case"
                + " Sensitive)");
        str = input.next();
        seatSelect = str.charAt(0);
        switch (seatSelect) {
            case 'A':
                colNum = 0;
                break;
            case 'B':
                colNum = 1;
                break;
            case 'C':
                colNum = 2;
                break;
            case 'D':
                colNum = 3;
        }//end of switch
        if (colNum > 3 || colNum < 0 || rowNum > 11 || rowNum < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
            return false;
        }//end of if
        if (plane[rowNum][colNum] != 0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, seat is taken");
            return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("This seat is available");
            return true;
        }//end of else
    }//end of isSeatAvail

    public static int reserveSeat(int[][] plane) {//asks user for input
        //reserves a seat based on user input, returns updated value to array
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rowNum;//Row number of seat chosen
        int colNum = 4;//Column number of seat chosen
        char seatSelect;//Character of seat chosen
        String str;//used to get char value for switch
        System.out.println("Choose which row you would like to reserve (1-12)");
        rowNum = input.nextInt() - 1;
        System.out.println("Choose which seat you would like: A,B,C, or D (Case"
                + " Sensitive)");
        str = input.next();
        seatSelect = str.charAt(0);
        switch (seatSelect) {
            case 'A':
                colNum = 0;
                break;
            case 'B':
                colNum = 1;
                break;
            case 'C':
                colNum = 2;
                break;
            case 'D':
                colNum = 3;
        }//end of switch
        if (colNum > 3 || colNum < 0 || rowNum > 11 || rowNum < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Selection");

        }//end of if
        if (plane[rowNum][colNum] != 0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, seat is taken");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Your seat has been reserved");

        }//end of if else
        return plane[rowNum][colNum] = 1;//return updated array value
    } //end of reserveSeat

    public static int seatsAvailInRow(int[][] plane) {//checks how many seats
        //are available in a row determined by user input returns how many seats
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rowNum;
        int rowSum = 0;
        int avail;
        System.out.println("Choose which row to see how many seats are"
                + " available (1-12)");
        rowNum = input.nextInt() - 1;
        for (int[] plane1 : plane) {
            rowSum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < plane1.length; j++) {
                rowSum += plane[rowNum][j];
            } //end of nested for
        } //end of for
        avail = 4 - rowSum;
        System.out.println("There is " + avail + " seat(s) available in that "
                + "row");
        return avail;//returns number of seats available
    }//end of seatsAvailInRow

    public static int findRowWithTwoSeats(int[][] plane) { //finds the closest
        //row that has 2 adjacent seats, returns row num, or 0 if none
        for (int i = 0; i < plane.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < plane[i].length; j++) {
            if (plane[i][0] + plane[i][1] == 0 || plane[i][1] + plane[i][2] == 0
                        || plane[i][2] + plane[i][3] == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Row " + (i + 1)
                            + " has adjacent seats");
                    return i;//returns row num with adjacent seats
                }//end of if
            } //end of nested for
        } //end of for
        return 0;//returns 0 if there is no adjacent seats
    }//end of findRowWithTwoSeats

    public static int countSeatsAvail(int[][] plane) {//counts how many seats
        //are available on the plane, returns int value for number of seats
        int count = 0;//used to keep track of how many seats are available
        for (int i = 0; i < plane.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < plane[i].length; j++) {
                if (plane[i][j] == 0) {
                    count++;
                }//end of if
            }//end of nested for
        }//end of for
        System.out.println("There are " + count + " seats available");
        return count;//returns the number of seats available
    }//end of countSeatsAvail

    public static int countTakenSeats(int[][] plane) {//counts number of seats
        //taken on the plane, returns int value for number of seats taken
        int count = 0;//used to keep track of how many seats are taken
        for (int i = 0; i < plane.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < plane[i].length; j++) {
                if (plane[i][j] == 1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }//end of nested for
        }//end of for
        System.out.println("There are " + count + " seats taken");
        return count;//returns number of seats taken
    }//end of countTakenSeats
}//end of class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main feedback is going to be that you aren't delivering in the right way. You only needed to create methods that could be used by a reservation system internally. You don't need to create the whole reservation system.

You should start with defining a `Plane` as being this thing that "has" some `seats`:

```
class Plane {
    int[][] seats = new int[12][4];
}
```

Then, `fillSeatsRandomly` sounds like they want you to write an operation that works on some particular `Plane` that can update the status of its seats.

```
class Plane {
    int[][] seats = new int[12][4];

    public void fillSeatsRandomly() {
        for ( int row = 0; row < seats.length ; row ++ ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And so on. Think about it as though your Prof. is going to take your code and write `main` for themselves. Though you can, and probably should, write your own `main` function to demonstrate your understanding. Just *don't* prompt the user. Instead, have it do hard-coded things using the randomized plane.

```
class Plane {
    int[][] seats = new int[12][4];

    public void fillSeatsRandomly() {
        for ( int row = 0; row < seats.length; row ++ ) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public boolean isSeatAvailable(int row, char column) {
        // ...
        // return (... == 0);
    }

    // ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Plane p = new Plane();
        p.fillSeatsRandomly();
        p.displaySeats();
        if (p.isSeatAvailable(4, 'C')) {
            p.reserveSeat(4, 'C');
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

I've dropped the word `static` from all but `main`. Do you understand why that is? If not, refresh yourself.